# Error while trying to insert a record to oracle database table via shell script in Linux

Tags: sql, linux, oracle, shell, sql-insert

Could anyone help me on resolving this error which I am getting when I try to run a shell script test.sh with parameter as 20211007
The code is as below:

```
#!/bin/sh

ODATE=${1}
file_source_sys="abc"
File_name="xyz"
file_deliver_time="20210218:12:56:76"

HOME_DIR="/var/tmp/Sneha"

source ~/env/INFORMATICA.env
source ${HOME_DIR}/db.properties

cd ${HOME_DIR}

cat <<EOD > temp.sql
INSERT INTO test VALUES 
('${file_source_sys}','${File_name}','${file_deliver_time}','$ODATE');

commit;

quit
EOD

sql ${USER}/\"${PASS}\"@${DB_INSTANCE} @temp.sql
```

The error is as below:

SQLcl: Release 18.3 Production on Sat Nov 06 18:53:24 2021 Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Sat Nov 06 2021 18:53:25 +01:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.11.0.0.0

Error starting at line : 1 File @ /var/tmp/Sneha/temp.sql
In command -
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('abc','xyz','20210218:12:56:76','20211005')
Error at Command Line : 1 Column : 13 File @ /var/tmp/Sneha/temp.sql
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Commit complete.

Disconnected from Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.11.0.0.0

Note I double checked and confirmed that table test is created in DB. Also I manually checked my inserting this insert statement generated into DB it is working fine. But via Shell script it is not happening.

Also I see the temp.sql file is generated with below content:

INSERT INTO test VALUES ('abc','xyz','20210218:12:56:76','20211005');

commit;

quit

I am not sure where in the code I am going wrong, as I can see the script is connecting to database successfully and also doing commit and disconnecting itself as well properly.

Your help is much appreciated.
Many thanks

Comment: Did you check that statement via SQL*Plus with the same credentials?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Given that you can connect and the Oracle error is quite clear, I can only imagine that you are using a different user or your user misses some privilege. What happens if you replace the insert with a `select * from test;`?

Comment: As a diagnostic test, how about having it print out the current instance and schema name?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are connected to the right database, it says that the table 'test' doesn't exist, try doing:

```
INSERT INTO DB_NAME.test VALUES (...);
```

Comment: I am connecting to a simulation database hence this error was coming, the actual schema and simulation schema are so much alike that I missed one one character in the hostname while connecting to actual schema. Many thanks for your suggestions. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am connecting to a simulation database hence this error was coming, the actual schema and simulation schema are so much alike that I missed one one character in the hostname while connecting to actual schema. Many thanks for your suggestions. :)